# Django, Best way to add data to Foreignkey field with ModelForm

Tags: python, django, modelform

I am playing around with django, ModelForms and i created PostModel and CommentModel with a foreign key. That is all post have a comment box which allow users to comment,here is my view which works perfectly i just want to know the best way i could have added the data to comment field

```
def comment(request, id):
try:
    post = PostModel.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = CommentForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            comment = form['comment'].value()
            post.postcomment_set.create(comment=comment)
            return redirect('all_post')

    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        context['form2'] = form
    return render(request, 'prac/comment.html', context)
except Exception as e:
    return HttpResponse(f'Error {e}')
```

form in templates

```
<form action="{% url 'comment' post.id %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{form2.comment.label}}<br>{{form2.comment}} <input type="submit" value="Comment"></p>
 </form>
```

everything works fine i just want to know the best way i could have handle data processing in my view

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `form.instance` instead, it contain new comment instance, so you can modify it before saving:

```
 if form.is_valid():
        form.instance.post = post
        form.save()
        return redirect('all_post')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
form = CommentForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    variable = form.save(commit=False)
    variable.fieldname = value # you can add here extra field 
    variable.save()
    return redirect('all_post')
```

or

```
form = CommentForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    variable = modelname()
    variable = form['comment'].value()
    variable.fieldname = value # you can add here extra field 
    variable.save()
    return redirect('all_post')
```